# Printing C++ Output to Text File

Tags: c++

I have a C++ code which I want the output to be printed in a text file. The output prints one at a time, meaning that when I open the text file there's an output and when I closed and reopened it there will be the other output. How can I make it so that every time it prints an output it all prints and stay in the text file so that I can see all the results in the text file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

float p(int N, int k, float R);

int main ()
{
    float R=0.158; float N=65;
    float mean = 0.0;  float ps=0.0;


    for (int k=1; k<=N; k++)
        {
            float prob=p(N,k,R); ps = ps+prob;
            mean = mean + k*prob;
            freopen ("output.txt","w",stdout);
            cout << k << " " << p(N,k,R) << endl;


        }
        cout << "ps: " << ps << " mean: " << mean << endl;

}

float p(int N, int k, float R)
{
    if (k==1)
        {
            return pow(R,N-1);
        }
    else if (N==k)
        {
            return pow(1-R,(k*(k-1))/2);
        }
    else
        {
            return p(N-1,k,R)*(1-pow(1-R,k))+p(N-1,k-1,R)*pow(1-R,k-1);
        }
}
```

Comment: How does the `p` function relate to the question itself? While it's not a lot of additional code, this example is not *minimal*.

Comment: Not only it contains too much, there seems to some stuff missing.

Comment: Use `freopen`. Open the text file as `freopen("myFile.txt", "w", stdout)` at the beginning of int main(), and close it before return 0. All `cout` output will be printed to that myFile.txt instead of the console.

Comment: An one minute google search pops up this. [How to use Files in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Comment: [freopen.3p - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3p.html) Mode: `"w  - Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file."` -- that's pretty clear. If you have C++ code -- why are you using C I/O to `freopen`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through all the feedback I got in this threat I already got my code to print the output into a text file as you can see in the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

float p(int N, int k, float R);

int main ()
{
    freopen ("output.txt","w",stdout);
    float R=0.158; float N=65;
    float mean = 0.0;  float ps=0.0;

    for (int k=1; k<=N; k++)
        {
            float prob=p(N,k,R); ps = ps+prob;
            mean = mean + k*prob;
            cout << k << " " << p(N,k,R) << endl;

        }
        cout << "ps: " << ps << " mean: " << mean << endl;
    fclose (stdout);
    return 0;

}

float p(int N, int k, float R)
{
    if (k==1)
        {
            return pow(R,N-1);
        }
    else if (N==k)
        {
            return pow(1-R,(k*(k-1))/2);
        }
    else
        {
            return p(N-1,k,R)*(1-pow(1-R,k))+p(N-1,k-1,R)*pow(1-R,k-1);
        }
}
```